# How to extract img src from div?

Tags: javascript

I would like to extract the image src from the following html div:

```
<div class="mini-cart-image">
  <a href="http://marmot.com/equipment-tents-6-person-tents/midpines-6p/889169900013.html">
    <img src="http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/marmot/29510_9821_f?$thumb$" alt="Midpines 6P, Orange Spice/Arona, small" title="Midpines 6P, Orange Spice/Arona"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

I extracted this div from the website using the following code:

```
var cart_image0 = document.getElementsByClassName("mini-cart-image")[0]
var cart_image0src = cart_image0.getAttribute('src') // null
```

I would like to return the value of the src. I thought of using getAttribute, but this returns null. Is there a way to do this using js methods? My alternative is manually parsing the innerHTML for the src value. I would hope there is a better solution I'm ignorant of.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName("mini-cart-image")` returns the div. Not the image.

Answer (score 4):

Try `querySelector`

```
var cart_image0 = document.querySelector(".mini-cart-image a img").getAttribute('src');
```

or remove `a` also from the selector

```
var cart_image0 = document.querySelector(".mini-cart-image img").getAttribute('src');
```

Comment: You could remove the `a` in the selector?

Comment: This works. Thank you. I will go read up on querySelectors. You can remove the a and the return is the same.

Answer (score 0):

What happen in your code is that you are selecting an element `var cart_image0 = document.getElementsByClassName("mini-cart-image")[0]` with no `src` attribute..

That's the reason you get null when calling `cart_image0.getAttribute('src')`

Code

```js
// Select the cart
var cart = document.getElementsByClassName("mini-cart-image")[0];

// Select the img in the cart
var img = cart.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

// Get the img src attribute with "img.getAttribute('src')" or shorter "img.src"
console.log(img.src);
```

```html
<div class="mini-cart-image">
  <a href="http://marmot.com/equipment-tents-6-person-tents/midpines-6p/889169900013.html">
    <img src="http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/marmot/29510_9821_f?$thumb$" alt="Midpines 6P, Orange Spice/Arona, small" title="Midpines 6P, Orange Spice/Arona"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

Notice that with `cart.getElementsByTagName('img')` you get a collection with all the images in the `cart`.. So you can iterate or use the very first `img` element, as in the code example, with `cart.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the `var cart_image0 = document.getElementsByClassName("mini-cart-image")[0]` isn't referencing the `img` element.

Try this:

```
var cart_wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("mini-cart-image")[0];
var cart_image0 = cart_wrapper.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]
var cart_image0src = cart_image0.getAttribute('src') // no longer null
```

---